# Notable to access folder in root directory

Tags: linux, codeigniter

I have my own site http://www.badrinathdham.com/

I used codeigniter framework, I can access all directly but can not access "media" folder in root...

badrinathdham.com/media/images/*
www.badrinathdham.com/media/css/*

Any idea what wrong i did?

Find htaccess code below

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#ErrorDocument 404 /home

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin/dashboard [NC]
```

Thank in advance

Comment: What are the permissions of the media directory? Does the user running the web-server (and by extension PHP and CodeIgniter) have read access to that directory?

Comment: I solved this problem thans for ur response, it was permission error.

I applied 755 permission to folder and 644 to files and now its working fine.....

Comment: Great! I'm glad you were able to sort it out! You should add an answer and select it so that this question is properly answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
site_url('media/images');
```

OR

```
site_url('media/css');
```